# How to save a neural network model in h5 with loss function "balanced categorical entropy"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, loss-function

I am using VGG16 for image segmentation with the loss function "balanced categorical entropy" using the code

```
beta=0.5

def balanced_cross_entropy(beta):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    weight_a = beta * tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    weight_b = (1 - beta) * tf.cast(1 - y_true, tf.float32)
    
    o = (tf.math.log1p(tf.exp(-tf.abs(y_pred))) + tf.nn.relu(-y_pred)) * (weight_a + weight_b) + y_pred * weight_b
    return tf.reduce_mean(o)

  return loss
```

Everything works fine. Now I save this model in the h5 file using the code.

```
vgg.save('vgg.h5')
```

But when I use the load_model from Keras

```
 model = load_model('vgg.h5', custom_objects={'balanced_cross_entropy(beta)': balanced_cross_entropy(beta)})
```

I encounter an error.

```
Unknown loss function: loss. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument.
```

Can anybody help, I suspect the problem may be due to beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only perform inference, you can avoid this problem by specifying

```
model = load_model('vgg.h5',compile=False)
```

Otherwise, you need to load the in the following way:

`model = load_model("vgg.h5", custom_objects={'loss': balanced_cross_entropy(beta)})`; in your code you wrote `balanced_cross_entropy(beta)` instead of `loss`.

Short explanation:

The name of the key in `custom_object` is actually the name of the inner function (which is in fact returned by `balanced_cross_entropy(beta)`; the name of the outer function is actually the value of the `<key,value>` pair in the `custom_object` dictionary.